# Render HTML data while generating PDF using PDFkit in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, pdf-generation, node-pdfkit

I need to generate a PDF file using 'PDFkit' library. Data is retreived from MySQL DB, some of the data contains HTML content. while rendering HTML data to PDF using 'html-to-text' library some of the tags are not rendered.

Ex: em,strong tags. Below is the sample code.

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const { htmlToText } = require("html-to-text");

const fs = require('fs');
const doc = new PDFDocument;

let htmlData = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>
The h1 element</h1>
<p>This is normal text - <em><strong>and this is bold text</strong><em>.</p>

<ol>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
`;

doc.text(htmlToText(htmlData), {
    width: 500,
    align: 'left'
});
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./file.pdf')); // write to PDF
doc.end();
```

what would be the best possible solution to render HTML data here?

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve this? I am kind of stuck on the same issue.
I am thinking of parsing the HTML using something like cheerio, then for each component, check its attributes and call doc.text() with appropriate parameters.